# How do I use the AWS CLI to find the uptime of servers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redhat, command-line-interface, rhel7, aws-cli

I've reviewed reference documentation for the AWS CLI.  I know how to use the `aws ec2 describe-instances` command.  Is there a variation to list the uptime (not the creation time) of the servers?  The OS uptime is useful.  It seems like this could be obtained via an aws cli command.

Comment: As with RAM and disk usage, it cannot be fetched via AWS API. Amazon doesn't have that sort of visibility inside your VMs.

Comment: You could use a configuration management system to get this information en mass, like SaltStack.

Answer (score 4):

There is no specific 'uptime' measure in Amazon EC2.

If [AWS Config](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/WhatIsConfig.html) has been configured, you could use `get-resource-config-history` to retrieve the history of an instance, eg:

```
aws configservice get-resource-config-history --resource-type AWS::EC2::Instance --resource-id i-1a2b3c4d
```

AWS Config will show the **state change** of an Amazon EC2 instance (eg `stopped`, `running`) as a `Configuration.State.Name` value. The change will also have a timestamp.

Using this configuration history, you could piece together enough information to calculate uptime.

Alternatively, you could **calculate the uptime from within the instance** (eg from system logs or via a custom app) rather than obtaining it from EC2.

Answer (score 1):

From the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html), you are probably after `LaunchTime`:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[LaunchTime]"
```

From there, you can calculate the offset from the current date and time to find the uptime.

Comment: Note that this assumes the instance has been up consistently since the launch time and has not been stopped/started in between.